# How can I import data from XML into a content type using the Migrate module?

Tags: migrations

I have activated the Migrate, the Migrate Plus, and the Migrate Tools modules. I have then imported a migration file at /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import.

```php
id: beetween_jobs
label: 'Migrate beetween jobs from XML file'
migration_group: default
source:
  plugin: xml
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
    # 'simple_xml' is configured to be able to use the 'http' fetcher.
    data_parser_plugin: simple_xml
    urls:
      - https://mywebsite/beetween.xml
    item_selector: /root/jobs
process:
  title: title
  field_diffusion: diffusion
  field_faculty : faculty
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: job
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

I could not find any official documentation, so I created that file basing on a tutorial.

On /admin/structure/migrate/manage/default/migrations, it doesn't list the migration I added. I just says:

> Il n'y a pas encore de Entités migration.
>
> Échec de connexion au serveur de base de données. Le serveur a renvoyé
> le message suivant : No database connection configured for source
> plugin variable.
>
> Est-ce que le serveur de base de données fonctionne ?
> Est-ce que la base de données existe et avez-vous saisi le bon nom de base ?
> Avez vous saisi les bons nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe ?
> Avez vous saisi le bon nom d'hôte de la base de données ?

Comment: For a start, I believe all of the keys under source need to be indented the same, i.e. they are all direct children of source.

Comment: While the second part of the error message talks about a database connection, I believe it can't connect to the migration source (which I believe is because it's indented improperly in your yml).

Comment: Pretty sure the migrate plus module has an examples folder that demonstrates some of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Kevin suggested, inspired by the

> migrate_plus.migration.wine_role_xml.yml

file from the migrate_plus module , i have managed to make it working as such:

```
id: beetween_jobs
label: 'Migrate beetween jobs from XML file'
migration_group: default
source:
  # We use the XML data parser plugin.
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  data_parser_plugin: xml
  # Normally, this is one or more fully-qualified URLs or file paths. Because
  # we can't hardcode your local URL, we provide a relative path here which
  # hook_install() will rewrite to a full URL for the current site.
  urls:
    - https://my_website/files/ressources_docs/beetween.xml
  # Visit the URL above (relative to your site root) and look at it. You can see
  # that <response> is the outer element, and each item we want to import is a
  # <position> element. The item_xpath value is the xpath to use to query the
  # desired elements.
  item_selector: /root/job
  # Under 'fields', we list the data items to be imported. The first level keys
  # are the source field names we want to populate (the names to be used as
  # sources in the process configuration below). For each field we're importing,
  # we provide a label (optional - this is for display in migration tools) and
  # an xpath for retrieving that value. It's important to note that this xpath
  # is relative to the elements retrieved by item_xpath.
  fields:
    -
      name: title
      label: 'title'
      selector: title
    -
      name: diffusion
      label: 'diffusion'
      selector: diffusion
  # Under 'ids', we identify source fields populated above which will uniquely
  # identify each imported item. The 'type' makes sure the migration map table
  # uses the proper schema type for stored the IDs.
  ids:
    title:
      type: string
process:
  # Note that the source field names here (machine_name and friendly_name) were
  # defined by the 'fields' configuration for the source plugin above.
  title: title
  field_diffusion: diffusion
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'
  default_bundle: job
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```